# Sharing Data between JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Today i was asked this question about sharing data from a thread t1 that runs in one jvm 1 to a thread 2 running in another jvm 2, and similarly to another thread t3 in jvm 3. after some homework i had told the following answer.kindly let me know if you have better and efficient answer.

1. SERIALIZATION
2. java nio Stream

> ```
> -------------                                                   -----------------
> jvm 1                  PASS THE DATA TO ANOTHER THREAD IN A         JVM2  
>
>                          NOTHER JVM
>                          ===============>>>>>  
> tHREAD T1                                                          tHREAD T2
> --------------                                                  -------------------
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it depends on the context of your application. You have multiple options:

- Serialization can work, but is very likely to break if your code changes. This can lead to data loss.
- To share data between multiple applications, you can use a database. That's one of the best option in my mind, since your data will be structured.
- Also, you can use a formatted text file. Just choose how to format your data, put that in a file, and then read the file from another application.
- If your JVM are on different computers, you can try using sockets. This way, your applications will be able to communicates via the network.
- If you can have a server acting like a relay for your objects, you can also use a messaging server (I'm thinking about JMS).